# CSS marquee only displaying text as wide as the page is

Tags: html, css, marquee

My marquee is only displaying my text as wide as the screen is. I'm not sure what options I have to make it display all the text, regardless of the screen width. I know my `width: 100%` style is the issue here.

```css
.example1 {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    /* Starting position */
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
    animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

.example1 h3:hover {
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
    <h3>LeBron sets tone at Cavs media day | Rajon Rondo breaks hand in fall | LeBron: Patience is key for Cavs | Jackson: Knicks can make playoffs | Grizzlies sign F Michael Beasley |
    </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your text is breaking into new lines. Add a `white-space: nowrap` to `example1` class to fix that.

Here's the snippet:

```css
.example1 {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap; /* <--- FIX */
}

.example1 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    /* Starting position */
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
    animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes example1 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

.example1 h3:hover {
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
    <h3>LeBron sets tone at Cavs media day | Rajon Rondo breaks hand in fall | LeBron: Patience is key for Cavs | Jackson: Knicks can make playoffs | Grizzlies sign F Michael Beasley |
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is it. If I make my browser fill the width on my desktop, it displays all the text properly. If I shrink it though, it only displays as much as the width will allow then cuts the rest off.

Comment: Exactly! That happens because the text breaks into new lines to fit the current screen width. By adding a `white-space: nowrap` you'll have only 1 line of text, allowing you to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thank you :) I already accepted a previous answer but this works as well.

Comment: You're welcome! I think it's important to take note that the other answer does not fix the issue, since it uses a static width. If you change to a bigger text, the width will need to be manually adjusted. By adding `white-space: nowrap`, you won't have to adjust the width. In my opinion, thats a better approach since it's dynamic. You can write the entire "Lorem Ipsum" and it will still work!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the width where the marquee runs, simply adjust the width of the parent div.

See below:

```css
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* change your width on this parent div */ 
  width: 200px;
  /* add white-space: no-wrap to display all text */ 
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.example1 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.example1 h3:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <h3>LeBron sets tone at Cavs media day | Rajon Rondo breaks hand in fall | LeBron: Patience is key for Cavs | Jackson: Knicks can make playoffs | Grizzlies sign F Michael Beasley |
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, that easy huh. This was the issue. Just curious for my own knowledge's sake- I can add any width into that parent div, and the marquee then displays all the text. Even if the width is small like 50 px. But if I remove the width style altogether from the parent div, text only displays until the width of the page is reached. Curious why this is? This was the issue though, thanks!

Comment: When you don't specify the width in the div, the width gets defined by its parent element. In your case, the div was taking the width of the body which is 100%.

Comment: @JimmyBlundell - My answer also had `white-space: nowrap` and solved the width issue. The other answer only accounted for the no-wrap and didn't show a width example... - Sad that you removed the accepted answer, but glad your issue is solved.